# Time Picker is not showing slider buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I have implemented a Time Picker. But it is not showing slider buttons, from where select time.

Please take a look at this image:

[image]

There are no errors in console.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#timeField").datetimepicker(
    {
    minDate: 0,
    timeFormat: "hh:mm TT"
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

Here are the plugins I am using:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" type="text/javascript">
```

What can be the problem ?

Comment: you need to inculde <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script> like this ..just download this plugin and attach to your code

Comment: @tamilmani I have already include it. Take a look at the last plugin

Comment: @Hassan Sardar: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @HassanSardar did you solve this? I'm currently having the same problem. Please post your solution as an answer (if found).

Answer (score 0):

**please refer this link:**

[example datetimepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/6FGgA/69/)

**or**

```
$('#basic').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",

        hourMin: 8,

        hourMax: 16,

        numberOfMonths: 2,

        minDate: 0,

        maxDate: 30
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your slider script include above the time picker script.